# Unmasking Client's data in SpringBoot?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

how to mask data in react js, send it to springboot and unmask the data in springboot and also do the reverse,, is there any library that I can use to do this?

I couldn't found a way to do the above.
Help would be appreciated.